# Nginx URL rewrite to remove folder from URL when its followed by certain subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

After I have upgraded my site I see that once I go live with new version some parts of the website URLs will not be redirected for gallery, blogs and files because of new structure. And there is no way fixing it within the CMS. So my goal is to use NGINX redirects.

I wonder do any of you know any NGINX rewrite tricks to make such redirects possible?

```
website.com/forums/blogs/ into  website.com/blogs/
website.com/forums/gallery/ into website.com/gallery/
website.com/forums/files/ into website.com/files/
```

I actually need the part forums dropped from the URL only and ONLY when the address is going for forums+blogs/gallery/files. Don't want to loose that google traffic.

So for example
    website.com/forums/blogs/entry123/my-dog/ is redirected to
    website.com/blogs/entry123/my-dog/

BUT
    website.com/forums/topic/my-dog/

is left alone and working just like before because the following subfolder is neither blogs or gallery or files.

I needed that once on Apache and this one worked but on Nginx I have no idea.

```
RewriteRule ^forums/(blogs|gallery|files)/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
rewrite ^/forums/(blogs|gallery|files)/(.*)$ /$1/$2;
```

Please note that `rewrite` directive accepts some flags wich meaning depends on where is it placed (is it inside a `server` or `location` block). Detailed documentation is [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite).

Comment: no, this method from automatic converters like https://winginx.com/en/htaccess does not work. In my case. it makes forums folder go 404.

Comment: Can you post your full nginx config?

Comment: I don't see any method of processing php scripts in your config - neither fastcgi with php-fpm nor using upstream service. I think this config is incomplete.